# Why is $\int \cos(n\arccos(\sin(x)) = \int \cos(nx)$ on $[-1, 1]$?

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

I would like to evaluate

> $$\int \cos(n\arccos(\sin(x)) dx$$

with $x \in [-1, 1],$ and I used a calculator do to so. At the very beginning, the calculator simplifies

$$\int \cos(n\arccos(\sin(x)) dx = \int \cos(nx) dx.$$

This looks like $\arccos(\sin(x)) = x$, but I don't see where this comes from.

Comment: Note that if $y=\arccos(\sin(x))$, then $\cos(y)=\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, but couldn't fit it in a comment.

As I wrote above, recalling that $\sin(x)=\cos(\pi/2-x)$ we obtain that
\begin{align*}\cos(n\cdot \arccos(\sin(x)))& =\cos(n\cdot\arccos(\cos(\pi/2-x)))=\cos(n\pi/2-nx )\\& =\cos(n\pi/2)\cos(nx)+\sin(n\pi/2)\sin(nx)\end{align*}
which is equal to $n\cos(x)$ iff $n=0\mod 4$.

Are we sure that the substitution is correct?

Comment: You  have a typo: $\cos(n\cdot\arccos(\cos(\pi/2-x)))=\cos(n\pi/2-n x )$.

Comment: You are right! Thank you